# Find a specific location lies inside a polygon/edge using mapbox/leaftlet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I have done the below code to create a layer and then found the coordinates which shows in the side div.
But when i click on the button i need to check whether the point(6,79) lies inside the polygon or on the edge of it.

I have used(mapbox/leaflet) to do all these.

So please do help me to get this done.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Show drawn polygon area</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.4/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.4/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:75%; height: 75%; border: 1px solid black;}
  #details { width:200px ; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black; float:right;}
  #details2 { width:80px ; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black; float:right}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="load();">
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-draw/v0.2.2/leaflet.draw.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-draw/v0.2.2/leaflet.draw.js'></script>
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-geodesy/v0.1.0/leaflet-geodesy.js'></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-pip/v0.0.2/leaflet-pip.js'></script>
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYXNoYW4iLCJhIjoiQzQySHN1QSJ9.K4xoMZqrVsWBgYTp70CYNg';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-i86l3621')//examples.map-i86nkdio')
    .setView([6.9344,79.8428], 10); 
var featureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
  edit: {
    featureGroup: featureGroup
  },
  draw: {
    polygon: true,
    polyline: true,
    rectangle: true,
    circle: true,
    marker: true
  }
}).addTo(map);
map.on('draw:created', showPolygonArea);
map.on('draw:edited', showPolygonAreaEdited);
function showPolygonAreaEdited(e) {
  e.layers.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    showPolygonArea({ layer: layer });
  });
}
function showPolygonArea(e) {
  featureGroup.clearLayers();
  featureGroup.addLayer(e.layer);
  e.layer.bindPopup((LGeo.area(e.layer) / 1000000).toFixed(2) + ' km<sup>2</sup>');
  e.layer.openPopup();
}
var drawnItems = new L.featureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;
    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    var shapes = getShapes(drawnItems);
    document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = shapes ;
});
var getShapes = function(drawnItems) {
    var shapes = [];
    drawnItems.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        if (layer instanceof L.Polyline) {
            shapes.push(layer.getLatLngs())
        }
        if (layer instanceof L.Circle) {
            shapes.push([layer.getLatLng()])
        }
        if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
            shapes.push([layer.getLatLng()]);
        }
    });
   return shapes;
};
function checkfunction(e) {
    shapes = getShapes(drawnItems);
    var bounds= drawnItems.getBounds();         
    for (var i = 0; i < latlong.length; i++){
        var hello =new google.maps.LatLng(6.9344, 79.8428);
        if(bounds.contains(hello)) {
                alert("Red");
            } else {
              alert("Green");
            }
    }
}
</script>
<div id="details" >
</div>
<div id="details2" >
    <input type="button" value="Check" id="check" onclick="checkfunction();" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
Ashan.

Comment: Make sure your question is clear, this will get more attention and quicker responses. Please follow posting guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit of a hard time understanding your code - for example, why does it use `new google.maps.LatLng` if you're using Leaflet?

Anyway, it sounds like you want to use a library for performing point in polygon tests. There's a library called [leaflet-pip](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip) from Mapbox, that will most likely do what you need. You can find an example here: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/point-in-polygon/

Comment: Dear Liedman, The checkfunction is used to try what i know. So it might be wrong. and i have tried the above link. But i am unable to check the point inside the polygon or not. If the question is not clear i  will point it down as below . - I want to create a polygon. - Save the coordinated of the polygon to the database. - Using two text boxes(latitude,longitude) i need to check whether that point coordinate( eg:6.9344, 79.8428 ) lies inside the polygon or not. Hope this is clear now. many thanks sir.